# Start foreground camera recording service in background

Tags: android

I'm developing app for enterprise which will be used in custom hardware setup without a display and Android 11. Now I'm debugging an app on a smartphone with a display (smartphone will be used as a platform in future but without a display). Android has a restriction (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#access-restrictions) for starting foreground services which are using camera or microphone in background, so I'm stuck here.

Is there any way to start this service without any user interaction? Maybe Device Policy Controller provides a way to remove this limitations?

Thank you.

P.S. App provides life safety features, user knows about filming and accepts it directly, also app informs user with text-to-speech announcement, so ethic side is ok here.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to start this service without any user interaction? Maybe Device Policy Controller provides a way to remove this limitations?

Yes. You can start your foreground service without user interaction. You can schedule your foreground service to start at a certain time using [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms) or periodic time using [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) or start it remotely for example using [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) or even start it based on some events using [BroadCastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts).

To start a foreground service in android O and above you must start showing a notification and specify foreground service types in manifest and at runtime. for example, in work manager, [it will be like this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running#declare-foreground-service-types-manifest).

To record video from foreground service, you can use [Camera](https://developer.android.com/training/camera) or [Camera2](https://developer.android.com/training/camera2) depending on your target android version. There is also [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) which I did not use in the foreground service.

To start your app when startup you can use [BOOT_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) broadCastReceiver. I hope this be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I already listening for BOOT_COMPLETED and my question is about these restrictions: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#access-restrictions
They don't let me to start a foreground service that uses camera in background.

Comment: I didn't test it in android 11. at worst, I think you can start a simple activity when you need to record a video. for that, you should get pop-up permission in some device like Xiaomi. But with this account, audio and video recording programs will no longer work easily. I need to do more research on this.